# Advanced custom field images

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using advanced custom field Wordpress plugin on a website.
I need to add meta data to Wordpress images so i created some field such as image author.
I need to echo the image and all the fields related to it.
How can i do it?
I tried to use the get_field() function with the image id, and it works, but i need it in every post.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to echo the author image and meta data for each post correct?

If so... you need to create a post loop which can serve this for every post on the page.

You can add the thumbnail, title and meta data as separate custom fields from ACF - you will then need echo these in the post loop (ideally in separate divs). After this is complete, you will need to echo the fields in the loop using the ACF php field codes seen in this [link](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/).

You also need to make sure that the posts echoing the desired fields are linked to the ACF fields you created.